How to add SSL for tus node server file upload
I have a file upload server which uses tus node library. The server works fine in http and I can able to upload files using the server but it doesn't work in https.
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
const { Server } = require("@tus/server");
const { FileStore } = require("@tus/file-store");
const express = require("express");

const host = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 1080;
const app = express();
const uploadApp = express();
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/domain.key`, "utf-8");
const certificate = fs.readFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/domain.crt`,
  "utf-8"
);

const credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
const server = new Server({
  path: "/uploads",
  datastore: new FileStore({ directory: "/files" }),
});

uploadApp.all("*", server.handle.bind(server));
app.use("/uploads", uploadApp);
https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on https://${host}:${port}`);
});

I tried to add SSL to my server, but I'm not able to upload now. I used uppy client for uploading files.
When doing inspect I found following.
https://localhost:1080/uploads - 201 created
http://localhost:1080/uploads/uploads/074599e62bb20ddc9304e0bf1c2b1c03 - (failed)net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
http://localhost:1080/uploads/uploads/074599e62bb20ddc9304e0bf1c2b1c03 - (failed)net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
...retrying

